# Visual C++ runtime : malloc returns pointer to already used memory (contains actual strings)

Tags: c++, malloc

I'm not sure if this is ok, but very often, when I use malloc to allocate memory for char* pointer I see this :

[Memory representation after malloc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6VK4.png)

but what I really expected is the pointer points to some garbage or '00'.

Allocated memory is pointing to  character 'c', memory that already contains some meaningful strings (not sure if those are data section? Import table?).

Note that, this is right after the entry point of the application and I'm sure there are no non-freed and invalid pointers. Can anyone tell me if this is a good or bad thing since I'm not sure about inner workings of memory allocation from the CRT ?

Comment: "but what I really expected is the pointer points to some garbage" Well, it _does_ point to garbage.

Comment: The `malloc` function doesn't initialize the data it allocates. It will simply contain what just happens to be there.

Comment: *points to some garbage* Do you expect to see scratched bytes, or bytes with paint peeled off, or bytes that smell funny?

Comment: Ok thanks @Someprogrammerdude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you free a block of memory it is just added back to the pool of blocks of memory available for future allocations (and is possibly coalesced with adjacent blocks), so it's not so strange that you get back the same block of memory that you freed before, especially if you keep asking the same size.

Now, no overwriting is generally done (unless you enable some debug options) since it would just be a waste of time<sup>1</sup>, so what you see is perfectly normal.

---

1. The operating system *does* overwrite freed memory pages when the allocator gives them back, but it's because the OS redistributes them to different process, and allowing possibly sensitive data to leak between different process would be a security risk. That's not the case for the C runtime allocator, given that code in the same process can already read all the process memory.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot for the clarification.